# How to create iframe JAVASCRIPT to JAVA in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, gxt

Can anyone help me to javascript into java in gwt, and I need one simple example for this and I am gonna one JavaScript(URL) user form in to Java.

Thanking you

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand you. Can you give us more details? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to one JAVASCRIPT page Into JAVA page using iframe in GWT on admin side..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [Frame](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) to create `iframe` in JAVA in GWT.

```
 public class FrameExample implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
      // Make a new frame, and point it at Google.
      Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com/");

      // Add it to the root panel.
      RootPanel.get().add(frame);
    }
  }
```

**Find more than 30 Code Examples here [Java Code Examples for Frame](http://programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame)**

Comment: @user3479835 If needed then have a look at the code examples.